# Interpretation of Simple Logistic Regression with Categorical Variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interpretation

I'm currently trying to interpret simple logistic regression with a categorical variable.

Description of variables: `"region"` = the beneficiary’s residential area in the US; a factor with levels `northeast`, `southeast`, `southwest`, `northwest`. `"charges_cat"`= which takes the value 0 (low) when charges are less than 10000 dollars and the value 1 (high) in all other cases.

```
> logm2<-glm(charges_cat~region, family=binomial)

Coefficients:
                Estimate
(Intercept)      0.01235
regionnorthwest -0.17888 
regionsoutheast -0.13337 
regionsouthwest -0.25351
```

My interpretation for b1 = regionnorthwest is:

```
> exp(-0.17888)
[1] 0.8362062
```

If the beneficiary is living in the northwest region of the US, the odds of charges being more than 10000 dollars is 16.38% lower than the odds of charges being more than 10000 dollars for a beneficiary who lives in the northeast region of the US, with southeast and southwest regions are fixed.

My question is; in a single logistic regression should I state the factor levels of the `"region"` are fixed, such as "with southeast and southwest regions are fixed." or there is no need to state the dummy variables of the `"region"` fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that in a saturated factor model like what you have above, "with southeast and southwest regions are fixed" is a superfluous. If you are in the northwest region, you are by definition not in the southeast or southwest region.

I find that it helps clarify my thinking to recognize that in this setting where you are just regressing on a single categorical variable, the model you fit is equivalent to (after some transformations of the coefficients) just reporting the values of $P(outcome | category)$, one for each value of the categorical variable. To be a bit more concrete about what I mean by this, I can read from the model coefficients you reported above that:

$P(charges\_cat|northeast) = \exp(0.01235) / (1 + \exp(0.01235)) = 0.5031$
$P(charges\_cat|northwest) = \exp(0.01235-0.17888) / (1 + \exp(0.01235-0.17888)) = 0.4585$
$P(charges\_cat|southeast) = \exp(0.01235-0.13337) / (1 + \exp(0.01235-0.13337)) = 0.4698$
$P(charges\_cat|southwest) = \exp(0.01235-0.25351) / (1 + \exp(0.01235-0.25351 )) = 0.4400$